# Performing twitter.search.tweets with empty query

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to create a python script to create a html file that will show my tweets from my homeline on a daily basis. So for example, my html file should have all tweets from Sept 12 in one html file or any given day that I pass the script.

My twitter version is:

```
$ pip freeze |grep twit
twitter==1.18.0
```

To do this I perform the following calls:

```
from twitter import *
today = datetime.date.today()
s=twitter.search.tweets(q='SEARCH', until=today, count=1)
# Get the max id from day before:
midb = s['search_metadata']['max_id']
```

Where q='SEARCH' is the search term that twitter is looking for. But I want to **not** have a search term/query as I'm finding the tweet id (unfiltered search) that will be used for the `since_id` parameter in this twitter homeline call without searching for a search term.

`statuses = twitter.statuses.home_timeline(count = tweet_count, since_id = midb)`

And then I loop through the `statuses` and create my html file that way.

To try and have no search term (Making SEARCH be "" or '', and ' ') does not work as twitter wants q= to have something in it.

Is there another way to get the id of the last tweet of a particular day  of my homeline tweets, giving it a datetime object?

Comment: It will be helpful to add what python twitter library and its version you're using in your question. You can find this by running "pip freeze | grep twitter"

Comment: I updated the main description with the twitter version used.

Comment: With my limited exploration of twitter's API. I'm guessing you can pull all tweets in your home timeline then filter the results for the current day. Or you can search common letter in your language of choice _e.g._ Borrowing from [common letters in English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language), the value of `q` could be `"e%20OR%20t%20OR%20a%20OR%20o%20OR%20i%20OR%20n"`

Comment: If you're trying to get a timeline then I think the search API is the wrong way to go. I'd suggest looking at the GetHomeTimeline or GetUserTimeline methods instead.

Comment: @AndyPiper - I am using the GetHomeTimeline method. See the whole description above.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - That is another way to do it (Filter through the home timeline and find where the date changes).